# How to transform Json lines to parquet with Python?

Tags: python, json, pandas, parquet

I need to do it with Python in a simple way. I'm trying with Pandas but I'm just starting and it's very difficult for me.

Now I'm trying with json2parquet:

```
try:
    input_filename= '/tmp/source_file'
    source_file = s3.get_object(Bucket="myBucket", Key="myJsonLinesFile")
    datajson = source_file['Body'].read()
    with open(input_filename, 'wb') as f:
         f.write(datajson)
    convert_json(input_filename, '/tmp/final.parquet')


except Exception as e:
    print(e)   
    raise e
```

but I'm getting below error:
  "errorMessage": "cannot mix list and non-list, non-null values",
  "errorType": "ArrowInvalid",

Answer (score 1):

If you are using pandas 0.25.3 version you can install fastparquet or pyarrow library and execute the below code

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})
>>> df.to_parquet('df.parquet.gzip',
...               compression='gzip')  # doctest: +SKIP
```

More details can be found here - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html

Below are the links to

1. fastparquet - https://pypi.org/project/fastparquet/
2. pyarrow - https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/install.html#using-pip

Comment: hi jjayadeep, my code must process files that not have the same schema, I don't now hoy many columns will have each file.
thank you for your answer, I'll read the links that you share.

Comment: Do you want to write the different schemas in the same parquet file?

Comment: `source_file = s3.get_object(Bucket=source_bucket, Key=key) datajson = source_file['Body'].read() con = pd.read_json(datajson, lines=True) con = con.astype(str) con.to_parquet(tmp_file, compression=None) `
this code it's working but when I run a query in Athena I found that a field in the parquet file is INT64 do I get below error: HIVE_BAD_DATA: Field xxxxxx's type INT64 in parquet is incompatible with type string defined in table schema

Comment: why con.astype(str) it's not casting this field? or the issue is in the to_parquet that infer the datatype? If this is the case how can I resolve it?